# Encrypting SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am going to write my own encryption, but would like to discuss some internals. Should be employed on several mobile platforms - iOS, Android, WP7 with desktop serving more or less as a test platform.

Let's start first with brief characteristics of existing solutions:

- SQLite standard (commercial) SEE extension - I have no idea how it works internally and how it co-operates with mentioned mobile platforms.
- System.data.sqlite (Windows only): RC4 encyption of the complete DB, ECB mode. They encrypt also DB header, which occasionally (0.01% chance) leads to DB corruption.*) Additional advantage: They use SQLite amalgamation distribution.
- SqlCipher (openssl, i.e. several platforms): Selectable encryption scheme. They encrypt whole DB. CBC mode (I think), random IV vector. Because of this, they must modify page parameters (size + reserved space to store IV). They realized the problems related to unencrypted reading of the DB header and tried to introduce workarounds, yet the solution is unsatisfactory. Additional disadvantage: They use SQLite3 source tree. (Which - on the other hand - enables additional features, i.e. fine tuning of the encryption parameters using special pragmas.)

Based on my own analysis I think the following could be a good solution that would not suffer above mentioned problems:

- Encrypting whole DB except the DB header.
- ECB mode: Sounds risky, but after briefly looking at the DB format I cannot imagine how this could be exploited for an attack.
- AES128?
- Implementation on top of the SQLite amalgamation (similarly as system.data.sqlite)

I'd like to discuss possible problems of this encryption scheme.

*) Due to SQLite reading DB header without decryption. Due to RC4 (a stream cipher) this problem will manifest at the very first use only. AES would be a lot more dangerous as every "live" DB would sooner or later face this problem.

---

EDITED - case of VFS-based encryption

Above mentioned methods use codec-based methodology endorsed by sqlite.org. It is a set of 3 callbacks, the most important being this one:

```
void *(*xCodec)(void *iCtx, void *data, Pgno pgno, int mode)
```

This callback is used at SQLite discretion for encrypting/decrypting data read from/written to the disk. The data is exchanged page by page. (Page is a multiple of 512 By.)

Alternative option is to use VFS. VFS is a set of callbacks used for low-level OS-services. Among them there are several file-related services, e.g. xOpen/xSeek/xRead/xWrite/xClose. In particular, here are the methods used for data exchange

```
int (*xRead)(sqlite3_file*, void*, int iAmt, sqlite3_int64 iOfst);
int (*xWrite)(sqlite3_file*, const void*, int iAmt, sqlite3_int64 iOfst);
```

Data size in these calls ranges from 4 By (frequent case) to the DB page size. If you want to use a block cipher (what else to use?), then you need to organize underlying block cache. I cannot imagine an implementation that would be as safe and as efficient as SQLite built-in transactions.

Second problem: VFS implementation is platform-dependent. Android/iOS/WP7/desktop all use different sources, i.e. VFS-based encryption would have to be implemented platform-by-platform.

Next problem is a more subtle: Platform may use VFS calls to realize file locks. These uses must not be encrypted. More over, shared locks must not be buffered. In other words, encryption at the VFS level might compromise locking functionality.

---

EDITED - plaintext attack on VFS-based encryption

I realized this later: DB header starts with fixed string "SQLite format 3" and the header contains a lot of other fixed byte values. This opens the door for known plaintext attacks (KPA).

This is mainly the problem of VFS-based encryption as it does not have the info that the DB header is being encrypted.

System.data.sqlite has also this problem as it encrypts (RC4) also the DB header.

SqlCipher overwrites hdr string with salt used to convert password to the key. Moreover, it uses by default AES, hence KPA attack presents no danger.

Comment: Across each of the platforms you mention, is there no pre-existing encryption system you can use? They say that "roll it yourself" encryption can be risky, since you may introduce security problems that would be detected in a good pre-made library.

Comment: Yes, each platform offers various encryption schemes. But I want also binary compatibility of both encryption scheme and key generation. That would require a lot of compatibility testing so it might be easier to rely on own implementation.

Comment: Plus even if I decided for platform encryption scheme, the first two questions would be still here.

Comment: I don't understand: 1) what are the problems with unecrypted header (I think every solution uses VFS, which means header gets encrypted, not doing so would be much harder), 2) why do you call using amalgamation 'advantage' and using source tree 'disadvantage' while there is no difference and you can switch between them freely, 3) what do you mean by 'co-operation with mobile platforms' (sqlite only writes files), 4) you wrote 'above mentioned problems' but did not actually listed the problems. It appears to me that you're overcomplicating the issue.

Comment: Hard to go into detail here. In case of codec-based solution the decision whether to encrypt DB header or not represents roughly one line in code. And in fact in case of VFS-based solution it would be just a little bit harder. But in this case you don't need to keep DB header unencrypted.

Comment: Have you talked to HWACI about SEE yet or are you just speculating? (Alas, the [website](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) is a bit sparse, but they do mention that you get the source and so can build it for all platforms that you want it for.)

Comment: Did I ever speculate about SEE implementation? All my statements refer to the public SQLite release - anybody can open sqlite3.c and verify them.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to hack db format or sqlite source code. SQLite exposes virtual file-system (vfs) API, which can be used to wrap file system (or another vfs) with encryption layer which encrypts/decrypts pages on the fly. When I did that it turned out to be very simple task, just hundred lines of code or so. This way whole DB will be encrypted, including journal file, and it is completely transparent to any client code. With typical page size of 1024, almost any known block cipher can be used. From what I can conclude from their docs, this is exactly what SQLCipher does.

Regarding the 'problems' you see:

- You don't need to reimplement file system support, you can wrap around the default VFS. So no problems with locks or platform-dependence.
- SQLite's default OS backend is also VFS, there is no overhead for using VFS except that you add.
- You don't need block cache. Of course you will have to read whole block when it asks for just 4 bytes, but don't cache it, it will never be read again. SQLite has its own cache to prevent that (Pager module).

Comment: Several questions. I'll react one by one. 1) I refer to the encryption implementation as endorsed by sqlite.org, hence no hacking.

Comment: 2) VFS-based ecryption is an option I did not mention originally. I see several problems here. It might compromise reliability or performance. I see problems with efficient flushing, for example. (Transaction safety etc.)  Random access necessitates ECB scheme etc. I see this as a potentially unsafe solution.

Comment: 3) I analyzed both SQLCipher and system.data.sqlite sources. The code is short and simple and it uses high-level services, not VFS.

Comment: @JanSlodicka I bet every encryption implementation, including the one offered at sqlite.org, uses VFS. Other options are simply much harder. There is no performance impact on VFS.

Comment: 4) @unencrypted header: Take e.g. sqlite3.c, find sqlite3PagerReadFileheader(). It bypasses codes and is used to query pageSize and several less important variables. Just look at how pageSize is used afterwards, it's fairly trivial. (0.01% chance of failute.) But - as I mentioned - this isn't a problem of VFS-implemented encryption.

Comment: @"every encryption implementation, including the one offered at sqlite.org, uses VFS": No, no, no. Look into the code, if you don't believe me. They use - what they call "codec". It's a middle layer between VFS and higher levels.

Comment: @JanSlodicka SQLite requires random access to pages, which means CBC over whole database is practically impossible (not matter what way you do it), unless you rewrite whole file each time, which is just too slow. I think SqlCipher claim about CBC actually means CBC inside one page (e.g. 64-bit block over 1024 bytes of data).

Comment: @JanSlodicka I can not find anything in SQLite3 API docs that would be called 'codec'. Can you point me to it?

Comment: @JanSlodicka Hacking into pager module (sqlite3PagerReadFileheader) is what I call 'much harder' way. I don't know why anyone would do that while there is VFS API. Perhaps that implementation was created before VFS was introduced?

Comment: @sqlite3PagerReadFileheader: It's not difficult, but I agree that this would be a hack. And I don't want to do it either. I want to use unchanged amalgamation sqlite3.c.

Comment: SQLite does read the page size from the file header. However, SQLCipher works around this while encrypting the file header itself by assuming the default page size of 1024 unless otherwise told by the application that the page size is different via a different pragma. This eliminates the chance of failure opening a database but still allows the header to be encrypted.

Comment: Have you uploaded this anywhere? I've been working on something like this, but have had some trouble. Before I spend a lot of time debugging it… :)

Answer (score 1):

Didn't get much response, so here is my decision:

- Own encryption (AES128), CBC mode
- Codec interface (same as used by SqlCipher or system.data.sqlite)
- DB header unencrypted
- Page headers unencrypted as well and used for IV generation
- Using amalgamation SQLite distribution

AFAIK this solution should be better than either SqlCipher or system.data.sqlite.

Comment: I'm interested to know why you think this solution would be better than SQLCipher? Leaving the DB header unencrypted can leak information about the contents of the database, and basing the code off the amalgamation distribution could make it harder to update in the future and limits access to the SQLite internals, and makes it more difficult to spot / test incompatibilities and difference between releases.

Comment: Amalgamation y/n is a matter of taste. It allows trivial upgrades. The users can customize sqlite on his own (WAL, for example) or  decide about sqlite version, he does not need to wait with sqlite fixes. It also allows full access to SQLite internals. (By including sqlite3.c into your c file.) I admit the danger that sqlite upgrade renders your encryption scheme as non-working, but consider it a rather theoretical possibility. (Could be formally solved by declaring compatibilty to specific sqlite versions.)

Comment: Which header bits are secret? I can't see any, but see several problems with encryption. Eg. sqlite reads wrong pgSize. Fallback decision (taking default 1024) is ok as long as a) pgSize is really 1024 (ok, you force it [less user options]), b) sqlite detects wrong size. b) is not fulfilled in 0.01% cases. Even worse, block ciphers such as AES can fail any time later when header is re-encrypted. (Eg. when change counter increases.) I never analysed consequences of another 2 hdr flags that are incorrectly read.

Comment: Just for fun here is another argument against DB header encryption: As more than 60 header bytes are well known, it allows plain text attack. I know, with a good cipher such as AES, it should not present any danger.

Comment: BTW, if you are interested in discussing SQLite encryption internals, we clould do it privately. It could help both of us.